# How to get the full stream URL in a Wowza module?

Tags: java, video-streaming, wowza

I am writing a module for Wowza media server.

How can I get the full URL to a stream within the `onPublish()` method in my implementation of `IMediaStreamActionNotify2`?

At the moment I can only find the stream name.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check the `Client` object. It contains a method to get the stream URI.

Something like this:.

```
@Override
public void onPublish(IMediaStream stream, String streamName, boolean isRecord,
        boolean isAppend) {
    IClient client = stream.getClient();
    String uri = client.getUri(); 
    // This will print rtmp://127.0.0.1/live in my test server
}
```

The `Client` object also contain methods to get the querystring by `client.getQueryStr()` and other handy methods you can see at server-side api documentation.